# winlogon.exe corrupted. Regular fixing methods do not work

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootloader, easybcd, winlogon.exe

In the morning, when I switched on my computer, I was faced with an error saying that winlogon.exe is missing or corrupted. I logged on to my USB OS and replaced the winlogon.exe on the computer (which was 298kb) with the one on my pendrive (which is 280kb). This method did not work. I went to EasyBCD and created a Boot Entry which allowed me to boot into my OS via the pendrive OS's bootloader. I also tried "sfc /scannow", with an administrator command prompt but that did not work either. Also, I booted off the Windows 7 installation CD and did Startup repair thrice but to no avail.

I cannot carry my pendrive with me and boot off of its bootloader, as that does not serve the purpose of a laptop; to be portable.

What can I do now?

PS: I have the ISO for Hiren's boot CD and can use that, if only I know how.

Comment: Perform a repair from the original installation media

Comment: I tried a startup repair thrice.

Comment: Then edit your post and state it so others can see.

Comment: @Dave I did it. Sorry, I forgot to mention it in my question.

Comment: You may have to be prepared to reinstall.